# Changing checkbox/font size within lists for ArcGIS Survey 123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am trying to change the font/selection bubble size for my lists in Survey 123. I know how to change the label sizes but changing that does not affect the text or checkbox size in the list. I tried changing the font size for the label within the choices tab lists as well but to no avail. How can I do this?

Below are some photos for reference on what I have done. I am very new to Survey 123.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about changing the title size for each question? You could try using something like this:

```
<span style="font-size:12px">VALUE GOES HERE</span>
```